# Post Data not working correctly Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a Route as below that will display a profile depending on the data in the url:

```
Route::get('/{region}/{summonername}', function () {
    return 'Summoner Profile';
});
```

I have a Form on the Home page which consists of a Input Box and Region Selector. I am posting this data to:

```
Route::post('/summoner/data');
```

The problem is that i don't know how i can convert the form data eg. Summoner Name and Region into the url format where the user will be displayed with the profile page and the url would be /{region}/{summonername}. Am i supposed to use a Redirect::to inside my controller? I feel like that is a crappy way of doing it. Any Suggestions?

Right now when i post the data the url displays as '/summoner/data'.

I hope this makes sense, let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: try to search urlencode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes :

```
Route::post('/summoner/data','ControllerName@FunctionName');

Route::get('/{region}/{summonername}', function () {
return view('SummonerProfile');
});
```

Controller:

```
public function FunctionName()
{
 $SummonerName = Input::get('SummonerName');
 $Region = Input::get('Region');
 return Redirect::to('/{$Region}/{$SummonerName}');
}
```

Hope this will work. Try it!

Using Routes:

```
Route::post('/summoner/data',function () {
 $SummonerName = Input::get('SummonerName');
 $Region = Input::get('Region');
 return Redirect::to('/{'.$Region.'}/{'.$SummonerName.'}'); 
});

Route::get('/{region}/{summonername}', function () {
return view('SummonerProfile');
});
```

Comment: Is using a Controller the only way?

Comment: No, you can use in routes also.But i am following this pattern, makes more easy and flexible.

Comment: Can you show me method of doing this using Route Only?

Comment: Fantastic i finally got it to work with this thank you :)

Comment: if you are doing for making api, the you have to send the data to the url in JSON format and in routes/controller : $Data = Input::Json()->all(); for capturing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to redirect:

```
Route::post('/summoner/data', function (Request $request) {
    return redirect()->url($request->region .'/'. $request->summonername);
});
```

Comment: The above is not working, it displays Summoner Profile from the below Route however it still displays /summoner/data?summonername ... Route::get('/{region}/{summonername}', function () {
    return 'Summoner Profile';
});

Comment: The order here is irrelevant since one is `get` and the other is `post`. Please show your form action.

Comment: action="/summoner/data"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the data from URL, just do the following

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('/summoner/data', function (Request $request) {
    echo $request->segment(1); // gives summoner
    echo $request->segment(2); // gives data
});
```

Comment: Essentially i need the user to post the data in the form and the website will use a Get parameter with the form data from my api so like url = /{region}/{summonername}